# how to manager multiple git projects into one github repo with different folder

Tags: git

I have such requirement:

Create One GitHub repo A_ROOT with 2 sub-folder B_FOLDER and C_FOLDER,

and now I use `git init` two local project B and C separately, 
How can I push local project B to B_FOLDER and project C to C_FOLDER?

EDIT
Why I need this :
I have one repo on `github`, I want to add folder like `examples` under my repo, and each example should be independent and `runnable`, and when I adjust the examples, I don't want to modify the main project.

Comment: Best practice is to put each project in its own repository. Unlike some other version control systems Git repositories are cheap, and trying to manage multiple projects in one repository is unnecessarily complicated. If you edit your answer with why you feel you need to put multiple projects in one repo we can better help.

Comment: @Schwern I've edit it to supply my reason

Comment: What do you feel is wrong about "modifying" the main project when you commit changes to the `examples` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I need this : I have one repo on github, I want to add folder like examples under my repo, and each example should be independent and runnable, and when I adjust the examples, I don't want to modify the main project.

While you can get what you want with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), that is an unnecessary complexity. What you describe is a normal project setup.

Simply have an `examples/` directory as part of the main project repository. Commit and push changes to it as you would any other directory. There's nothing wrong with "modifying the main project" by committing to the `examples/` directory. It is beneficial to keep the examples with the source code so they remain in sync as the project changes. There will be many times when a change to the project code requires an update to the examples.

---

There may be some circumstances were you want a different process for `examples`.

If you wish to distribute the `examples` separately, that should be done with a release tool. I can't tell recommend a release tool for your project, but I can recommend that Git is not a release tool.

If your project has an expensive review or test suite which runs on every commit or Pull Request, change your process to use an abbreviated process for changes which only touch the `examples` directory. You can check which files were changed in a branch with `git diff master --name-only`. And you can see which files were changed in the previous commit with `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD`.

Comment: you type the most , you win :)

Answer (score 1):

Submodules should be able to solve your problem.

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other.
>
> ...
>
> Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules